# How to get sub-dependencies of a dependency added as a git submodule

Tags: git, go, dependencies, git-submodules, go-modules

Let's say I am working on a Go project, called *X*, which has a dependency upon a repo *Y*.
I am not using go mods in my project *X* yet.

I have now added *Y* as a git submodule in my project *X* in the vendor pkg using the following command:
`git submodule add <URL to Git repo> <Directory in vendor pkg>`.

The repo Y has sub-dependencies on a project, say *Z* defined inside it in **Gopkg.toml** and **go.mod** files. Now, when I put my code to a server and run the following command to fetch the submodule *Y*, files of dependency *Z* are still missing.

What should I do to download the files for *Z* using the *Gopkg.toml* and *go.mod* files without explicitly going into *Y* and downloading.

Comment: "without explicitly going into Y and downloading"; is there a reason you don't want to do this?

Comment: @Alex yes, so while I deploy using Jenkins job, I dont have to use brute-force to make it work. I should be able to execute commands at the root level of project X.

Comment: "I am not using go mods in my project X yet." Then you are doing it **wrong** and there is no way to help you. Use Go modules now, everywhere.

Comment: @Volker I have modified a vendor pkg, hence unable to shift to go mod.

Comment: "I have modified a vendor pkg" So you forked a dependency. Then just import that forked dependency. Or `replace` that dependency with your fork. This is a XY problem. You either can do it the hard way and work against the tooling or do it the easy way and work with the tooling.

Comment: @Volker Agreed. I was think XY problem as well when I read that comment, hence my answer below.

Comment: Use Go modules. They support everything you're trying to do, and it does so cleanly. Using unsupported tools, as you are attempting, leads to a mess, as you are experiencing.

Comment: I had to use pre-module Go with a dependency manager for a while. Using the modules is *much* better.

Comment: Got it @Flimzy, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Rajvir You provided the relevant information in a comment and your question is a typical XY question so I see no problem with a downvote. Also: There is no need I add a second answer, I just upvoted VonC's.

Answer (score 3):

> "I have modified a vendor pkg, hence unable to shift to go mod"

Actually, you can reference Y in your go.mod, using a [`replace` directive](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive).

```
replace example.com/original/import/path => vendor/Y
```

That way, a [`go mod tidy`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-tidy)/[`go mod download`](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-download) should download `Z`.

Comment: Thanks @VonC for providing the solution for that